# game center not working on ipod/iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

Hi all
Working on a universal build for an iphone/ipod/ipad app. I was trying to get game center working within this app. I now have the game center working on the ipad but for some reason it still wont work on the ipod/iphone and i have no idea why.

```
highScoreVC=[[UIViewController alloc] init];

    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:highScoreVC.view];
        [highScoreVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated: YES];
    }
```

this is my code for displaying the leaderboard and it does work everytime for ipad but as i said not for other devices. the code is still being called the same as for ipad so i have no clue why it is not displaying. any ideas why this would be? cheers

Comment: Are you sure the iPhone and iPod touch you're testing on support Game Center? Older devices don't.

Comment: yeah they both do. the code worked with them before the project was converted to the universal build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it working in the end.
cocos2d 0.99.5 has indeed made some changes that to how this works. the following code displays the leaderboard correctly

```
-(UIViewController*) getRootViewController{
return (UIViewController*)([(BubbleDreamsAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController]);
```

}

and then

```
highScoreVC = [self getRootViewController];


    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;

        [highScoreVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated: YES];


    }
```

hope this helps anyone that gets stuck with same problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, `[GKLeaderboardViewController init]` will return `nil`  if the device is not authenticated with Game Center by that point. Are you sure you are correctly authenticated on the devices causing problems?

Comment: [GKLeaderboardViewController init] doesnt return nil here anyway and i have stepped through the code to be sure that it is getting into the rest of the code.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work" from your original post.

Comment: the game center just doesnt get displayed on the iphone or ipod. the actually game center leader board itself but without changing any code it does get displayed on the ipad. i just press the button on my app for game center and nothing visually happens but the code gets called each time.

Comment: and it is signed into game center sandbox. i get the welcome back screen when the app starts

Comment: just remembered im now using coco2d 99.5. and i see they have made some changes and use a rootViewController. can anyone tell me what changes i need to make to my code to use this new rootViewController

Comment: Have you looked through the release notes for 0.99.5?  Not completely sure of your needs but you're answer might be in there (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/release_notes:0_99_5).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be some issues with how your UIKit items for Game Center are being displayed if they are working fine on the iPad but not iPhone/iPod.  I experienced similar sounding issues when converting an app to universal.

If you create a new standalone iPhone/iPod project just for testing does game center display fine?

Comment: its nearly 4 in the morning here so i reckon ill call it a night and try make a standalone ipod project again in morning. what issues did you have with the UIKit? that sounds like it could be it as it was working fine up until the universal build was made

Comment: For me the issue was that all my xib interfaces went completely out of wack after creating a universal build probably because I didn't have a bunch of sizing/framing/dimension issues setup correctly.  Buttons and table views that appeared properly for iPhone/iPod were shown in the wrong position or off screen completely after going universal.

Comment: i made a standalone project with cocos22d 0.99.5 and it didnt work but then made a 0.99.4 standalone project and it did work. so guessing a change there is getting in my way. i read the change log but i still cant figure out how to get it displayed

Comment: Hmmm... yeh I guess there is something in 0.99.5 that's causing issues.  I would suggest doing a search on cocos2D forums (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/) and/or posting a question there.